# Cannot set node attribute using ansible XML

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible

I'm trying to setup a task that will add new attribute, if missing, to an XML element. My XML file is quite large, so I have included a snippet of it:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
        </subsystem>
```

The Ansible task is

```
- name: Turn on proxy address forwarding support for http
  xml:
          path: /opt/keycloak-quickstarts-latest/keycloak-server/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
          xpath: //http-listener
          value: "true"
          attribute: "proxy-address-forwarding"
```

My problem is that the task above fails with `Can't process Xpath / in order to spawn nodes!`. I have attempted this using ansible 2.7.8 and 2.8.1.

Comment: The issue is probably the default namespace `urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0`. Not sure how ansible handles namespaces though.

Comment: i'm not sure, but try to help, i feel like your xpath expression shall be : `xpath: /subsystem/server/http-listener`

Comment: FWIW, [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/xml_module.html) explicitly has an example showing the use of `namespaces:` which is required for your document, as @DanielHaley correctly pointed out

Comment: Since we are managing JBoss using Ansible as well: do not change the configuration via Ansible (or worse sed). It has the potential to break on the next JBoss release. Instead use the JBoss-CLI to manage the configuration because it is intended for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cudos to @daniel-haley and @matthew-l-daniel, the following task worked:

```
---
          path: /opt/keycloak-quickstarts-latest/keycloak-server/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
          xpath: //undertow:http-listener
          value: "true"
          attribute: "proxy-address-forwarding"
          namespaces:
                  domain: "urn:jboss:domain:8.0"
                  undertow: "urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0"
```

Hadn't understood the namespace section even though I had even tried it.